# Why does batching DELETE not decrease redo/undo generated UNLIKE INSERT/UPDATE in Oracle

Tags: oracle, dml, redo

I tested INSERT/DELETE/UPDATE of 10000 rows into a table(with indexes), whose average row length is 230 bytes in Oracle 12.2, both row by row and all rows at a time.
I saw expected results for bulk INSERT generating 5-6 times less redo and touching 6 times less db blocks resulting into significant performance improvement of 10-25 times, but UPDATE/DELETE test left me puzzled. I see no difference there. Neither in amount of redo nor in speed.
Does someone have an explanation why UPDATE/DELETE behaves that way?
It may happen that all 10000 rows reside in 10000 blocks, however, usually it is not the case. In addition in this test UPDATE worked just on a few blocks since it modified rows that were just inserted. The same with bulk DELETE.

```
set serverout on
set timing on
spool redo_test.log
drop table redo_test;
create table redo_test(cn1 number primary key, cn2 number, cd3 date, cv4 varchar2(128));

-- ===================== INSERT ==================================

SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

PROMPT ==== INSERT ROW BY ROW
-- slow by slow
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000 LOOP
    INSERT INTO redo_test VALUES (
      i,
      i,
      TO_DATE('06-MAR-2020 06:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + i / 24,
      'abracadabraabracadabraabracadabraabracadabraabracadabra' || TO_CHAR(i)
    );

  END LOOP;
END;
/

SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

ROLLBACK;

-- Interesting to see almost the same amount of redo.
-- Undo vector remains the same, which is understandable.
SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

PROMPT ==== Batch Insert
-- Batch all together
DECLARE
  lt_number    sys.dbms_utility.number_array;
  TYPE tt_date IS
    TABLE OF DATE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  lt_date      tt_date;
  lt_varchar   sys.dbms_utility.dblink_array;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000 LOOP
    lt_number(i) := i;
    lt_date(i) := TO_DATE('06-MAR-2020 06:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + i / 24;
    lt_varchar(i) := 'abracadabraabracadabraabracadabraabracadabraabracadabra' || TO_CHAR(i);
  END LOOP;

  FORALL i IN 1..10000
    INSERT INTO redo_test VALUES (
      lt_number(i),
      lt_number(i),
      lt_date(i),
      lt_varchar(i)
    );

END;
/

SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

rollback;


SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

PROMPT ==== Batch Insert Table of records
-- same batch insert, but with table of records this time
-- Curious to see if there is going to be any difference in redo/undo
DECLARE
  TYPE tt_rec IS
    TABLE OF redo_test%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  lt_rec tt_rec;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000
  LOOP
    lt_rec(i).cn1 := i;
    lt_rec(i).cn2 := i;
    lt_rec(i).cd3 := TO_DATE('06-MAR-2020 06:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + i / 24;
    lt_rec(i).cv4 := 'abracadabraabracadabraabracadabraabracadabraabracadabra' || TO_CHAR(i);
  END LOOP;

  FORALL i IN lt_rec.first..lt_rec.last
    INSERT INTO redo_test VALUES lt_rec(i);

END;
/

SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

COMMIT;

-- ===================== UPDATE ==================================
-- Yes, the test may be skewed a bit
-- because it deals with only available blocks
-- whereas in real life all 10000 rows just happen to be in 10000 different blocks
-- Yet, the ability to batch update exists.

PROMPT ==== UPDATE ROW BY ROW
-- Update Slow by Slow
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000 
  LOOP
    UPDATE BIDBOX.redo_test
    SET
      cn2 = i,
      cd3 = TO_DATE('06-MAR-2020 06:00:00', 'DD-MON-YYYY HH24:MI:SS') + i / 24,
      cv4 = cv4
    WHERE
      cn1 = i;

  END LOOP;
END;
/


SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

rollback;


SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

PROMPT ==== BATCH UPDATE
-- Batch Update
DECLARE
  TYPE tt_rec IS
    TABLE OF redo_test%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  lt_rec tt_rec;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO lt_rec
  FROM redo_test;

  sys.dbms_output.put_line('lt_rec.count'||lt_rec.count);

  FORALL i IN lt_rec.first..lt_rec.last
    UPDATE redo_test SET ROW = lt_rec(i)
    WHERE cn1 = lt_rec(i).cn1;

END;
/

SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

rollback;


SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

-- ===================== DELETE ==================================
PROMPT ==== DELETE Row by Row
-- DELETE Row by Row
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..10000 
  LOOP

    DELETE BIDBOX.redo_test
    WHERE cn1 = i;

  END LOOP;

END;
/


SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

rollback;


SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );


PROMPT ==== Batch Delete
DECLARE
  TYPE tt_rec IS
    TABLE OF redo_test%rowtype INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
  lt_rec tt_rec;
BEGIN
  SELECT *
  BULK COLLECT INTO lt_rec
  FROM redo_test;

  sys.dbms_output.put_line('lt_rec.count'||lt_rec.count);

  FORALL i IN lt_rec.first..lt_rec.last
    DELETE redo_test
    WHERE cn1 = lt_rec(i).cn1;

END;
/

SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

rollback;


SELECT
  sn.NAME,
  mst.value
FROM
  v$mystat     mst,
  V$STATNAME   sn
WHERE
  mst.STATISTIC# = sn.STATISTIC#
  AND sn.name IN (
    'db block changes',
    'redo size',
    'undo change vector size'
  );

spool off
```

Thank you

Comment: I don't see what this has to do with a batch-file.  A batch SQL operation is not a batch-file.

Comment: How detailed of an answer are you looking for?  A superficial answer is that Oracle is able to combine multiple insert changes into one change, but does not do the same trick for deletes.  [This presentation](https://www.slideshare.net/riyajshamsudeen/redo-internals-ppt) by Riyaj Shamsudeen explains some of the details.  However that still doesn't completely answer the question as it's not obvious to me why Oracle couldn't apply the same trick to deletes.  (Also, you may want to post your test code, as I was unable to see an improvement for UPDATEs either.)

Comment: Thank you very much for the link to the presentation.

I probably really wanted Batch UPDATE perform as well as BATCH INSERT:-)
I re-ran my test and it is clear that only INSERT really benefits from batching rows. Once I figure out how to post code and run results I will immediately do that

Comment: @Jon Heller Although the presentation did not explain why BULK UPDATE/DELETE produce as much redo as single row UPDATE/DELETE it was a useful reminder as to how to minimize redo generation.